# Best way for users to be able to permanently view links when hovering over area in web page?

Tags: hover

[Craftime Test site](http://craftime-bs6.businesscatalyst.com/)

Hi,

If you view test page attached and the useful links section on the right hand side below the menu, when you hover next to "click here if you would like to contact Craftime " you will see an email contact address and below this a link to Facebook.

I would like users to be able to permanently see these links. I can't work out where to adjust CSS I think it may be appearing as white so you can't see the text.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Kind regards, Matt.

Answer (score 0):

layout.css, line 35

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Remove the `color: #fff;` line to make it visible always.